# Determine that if $a_n \longrightarrow L$ then $\sqrt[n]{a_1\cdot...a_n}\longrightarrow L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinitesimals

I managed to prove that when $a_n \longrightarrow L$ then $\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}} \longrightarrow L$, and $\frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}\longrightarrow L$, and all these things scream the arithmetic/geometric mean inequality at me, but the only direction I could think of was getting an a larger sequence from the inequality to use as the upper bounding sequence in the squeeze theorem.

How can I get a lower bounding sequence to squeeze in the original sequence? Is there an alternative method?

Comment: what if $a_1=0$?

Comment: You need the sequence to have $a_i>0$ for all $i$ to make sense. Then take $b_n=\log a_n$ and apply $b_n\to \log L.$ Apply that $\frac{b_1+\cdots+b_n}{n}\to\log L.$ You'll need some special case argument for when $L=0.$

Comment: $n/(1/a_1+...+1/a_n)\le\sqrt[n]{a_1...a_n}\le(a_1+...+a_n)/n$ when the $a_i>0$.

Comment: @Thorgott How do you know that the leftmost operand is smaller than the one in the middle?

Comment: Well, if you know the right inequality (which I believe you do), then apply it to the numbers $1/a_1,...,1/a_n$ (still positive) and rearrange to get the left inequality.